# How to save Logged User in Hibernate Envers audit table?

Tags: hibernate, java-8, audit, hibernate-envers

I just imported hibernate-envers 5.0.7 Final to my project dependencies. And everything is working fine with the "AUDITED" part. But I'd like to save the session's Logged User to the audit table as well (So it's possible to know which user changed what). Is there a way to implement that?

Currently i'm only using the annotation `@Audited` in my `Entity` class. So the audit table and the `REVINFO` table are working fine. But how would I "add" data to be audited, that's not mapped to the entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data is important for audit you need to add it to entities, with a updateUser et updateDate properties.

Comment: I ended up creating a field in the entity that I update everytime I call my "save" function. In my project we use DAOs to save the object and they receive the logged user already. Thanks!